# Neither the property "getFollowed" nor one of the methods "getFollowed()", "getgetFollowed()"/"isgetFollowed()"

Tags: php, symfony

I have a many to one relationship between Users and Books and in the Follow table  I am attempting to get the object properties of users related to books. Bellow is the relationship definition in the Followed table

```
/**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
     */
    private $followed;
/**
     * Set followed
     *
     * @param User $followed
     *
     * @return Follow
     */
    public function setFollowed(Users $followed = null)
    {
        $this->followed = $followed;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get followed
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function getFollowed()
    {
        return $this->followed;
    }
```

Below is my controller definition passing control to the twig

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $me = $this->getAuthedUser(1);

        $follows = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Follow")->findBy(["follower" => $me]);
        $followeds = [];
        foreach ($follows as $follow) {
            $followeds[] = $follow->getFollowed();
        }

        $followables = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:User")->findAll();



        return $this->render("@App/index.html.twig", [
            "me" => $me,
            "followeds" => $followeds, //this
            "followables" => $followables,
        ]);
```

On attempting this in my view I am getting error in this line of code

```
{% if followed.getFollowed() %} //error at this line of code
```

This is the error

> Neither the property "getFollowed" nor one of the methods "getFollowed()", "getgetFollowed()"/"isgetFollowed()" or "**call()" exist and have public access in class "Proxies__CG**\AppBundle\Entity\User".

Comment: have you generated the getters and setters ?

Comment: yes I have and here it is

Comment: or do u know how I can do it in the controller and pass it to the view Tx

Answer (score 0):

In your view it’s not necessary to call getFollowed.
Just do that : {% if followed.followed %}

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `getFollowed()` method on an `User` object, but the actual method implementation seems to be in the `Follow` class (if that's the name of the class from your first code section).

Comment: getFollowed() is defined in the Followed class

Comment: but the object you're calling it on is an instance of the User class

Comment: yeah. because Follow is related to the User class

Comment: @Angelov is right, thats probably the correct answer. Don't put it aside! There simply is no `getFollowed()` on `User`.

Comment: Doing it in the controller is more efficient